# Convert TLB file to assembly with custom assembly information

Tags: .net, tlbimp

I am using tlbimp.exe to generate an assembly from a TLB file. I know that I can use the "asmversion" command line switch to set a custom version number, but how do I set the other information? I would like to set the fields like "Product Name" and "Company", but I don't see a way to do this. Can it be done with tlbimp, or any other tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tlbimp.exe to insert this information, at least in the latest (beta) version of Visual Studio 2010.  (I can't quite tell if these are new options.)

```
C:\Temp>tlbimp /?
Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Type Library to Assembly Converter 4.0.20624.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Syntax: TlbImp TypeLibName [Options]
Options:

    ...
    /product:Product         The name of the product with which this assembly
                             is distributed
    /productversion:Version  The version of the product with which this
                             assembly is distributed
    /company:Company         The name of the company that produced this
                             assembly
    /copyright:Copyright     Describes all copyright notices, trademarks, and
                             registered trademarks that apply to this assembly
    /trademark:Trademark     Describes all trademarks and registered trademarks
                             that apply to this assembly
    ...
```

Comment: Those options are definitely not in the VS2008 version. Do you know if an assembly generated with the 2010 version of tlbimp will work with a VS2008 app?

Comment: I'm not sure; I'd *assume* it should work fine with a VS2008 app, but I haven't tried that.